# Regex pattern in Pandas Series.str.extract() not pulling single digit day from column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I am attempting to use `regex`, extracting a date from `df['Subject']`, on a dataframe series/column and creating a new column `df['Date']` with the resulting date extraction.

The following code is extracting most column dates:

Code:

```
df['Bug Date'] = df['Subject'].str.extract('(\s\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\d{4})')
```

Input: Typical text row in the `df['Subject']` column:

```
'Call Don today [atron@uw.edu.au - Wed Apr 14 00:18:50 2021]'
' Report access [rbund@gmail.com - Mon Apr 4 13:11:12 2021]'

Output: 'Wed Apr 14 00:18:50 2021'
        'Mon Apr 4 13:11:12 2021'
```

A few of the dates however, all single digit, show up as `NaT`. Another option I am trying is:

I get no errors, and no changes, in this code:

```
option1 = '(\s\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{1}\s\d{4})'
df.replace({'Bug Date':'NaN'},{'Subject':option1},inplace=True)
```

with Pandas:

```
DataFrame.replace(self, to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad')
```

Help would be appreciated. Why doesnt `d{1,2}` work on some single digit days and not others? After careful analysis of the strings, I see no difference. However, the bug is consistent. 4 rows containing single digit string for day of the month change to `NaN`, while many other single digit rows do transfer well to the new column.

Here are a few rows of data. The first 4 are the trouble rows, out of about 200 rows with single and double digit day 'strings':

````
'Re: report [karen.glass@google.edu - Fri Apr 2 09:27:38 2021]', #results in NaN
'Re: report [hong.li@msoft.edu - Mon Apr 5 09:39:37 2021]',     #results in NaN        
'Re: report [sdgesmin@563.com - Wed Apr 7 09:21:02 2021]',     #results in NaN
'Re: report [pdefgios@utonto.ca - Thu Apr 8 12:40:28 2021]',   #results in NaN
'Re: report [zhuig-li7@mail.ghua.edu.cn - Tue Apr 13 02:38:51 2021]', #Good
'Re: report [l4ddgri@eie.grdf - Mon Mar 8 12:50:34 2021]' #Good,
'Re: report [luca.jodfge@ki.sfge - Thu Apr 8 23:52:20 2021]' #Good```


After many a trial and error, I ended up using:

```    df['Bug Date'] = df['Subject'].str.slice(start=-25,stop=-1).str.pad(25)
````

So this string of date and time column creation gave me no errors but when I tried to convert to_datetime a random error date would pop up. So I gave and extra space within the to_datetime( format= ) code from:
`'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`
to
`' %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`

and that seems to have done the trick. <fingers_crossed>

Comment: Can you show examples of the non matching lines? Did you try \d\d? instead?

Comment: Please add sample data which fails, otherwise we cannot answer your question and it will likely be closed as non-reproducible (since it works for all the sample data in the question as it currently stands)

Comment: Your code extracts the sample data correctly in my setup.  What's the version of pandas you are using ?

Comment: the \d\d gave me all NaNs. Also, I've pulled the small set of data that returned NaN and ran it through the script. It worked so I'm just looking for perhaps a different way to parse the series data into a new column than what I'm using. I've tried the or "|" option, not sure if I used it right but didnt work and no error.

Comment: All the values you've posted work fine for me. Try cutting and pasting the values from your question into your code and see if they still return `NaN`. If they don't, it means you have some non-ascii characters in the original strings.

Comment: I got no errors either playing with the 4 rows that keep getting left out of the regex. It looks like there are several different methods that can be used. I do have an OLD version of python 2.7.16. Perhaps there was an issue with that version and regex. I will update and see.

Comment: The update to python 3.8 version didnt help. I still get the same 4 items returned as NaN. I'll look for non-ascii char, perhaps try another method, and look over the rows for comparisons.

Comment: I ended up using: